# What's the behaviour of decision tree classification if the Y (i.e true labels) have the same values

Tags: classification, cart

I know that input data is not of much use, but I still want to understand how are we going to split the data (in the decision tree) in this case (because all the features should end-up giving the same amount of information gain)

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It will probably depend on your specific implementation what happens in this edge case, but the most reasonable assumption is that there will simply be no splits at all.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - If I use the information gain to split the nodes, then for this case are you saying that since there's no other value for target variable, we don't really have anything to put on the other side of the tree, right?

Comment: Exactly. Splitting gains no information, does not reduce Gini impurity, and so on and so forth: splitting does not help in any way, so any reasonable implementation should not split at all. (But edge cases are typically where the fun bugs are.)